# движение объекта turtle

Tags: python

на курсах задали сделать мини игру с помощью turtle, там есть основной персонаж, 2 врага и 1 цель, нужно докоснуться до цели чтобы пройти, а если докасаешься до врагов, то проигрыш, я столкнулся с 2 проблемами:

1. Как узнать соприкоснулся ли я с целью, или с врагом
2. Как запрограммировать движение врага, он двигается влево-вправо, первый имеет координаты 100;75,второй -100, 0, и если первый по иксу стал - 100, то надо идти влево, но он у меня дергается из стороны в сторону, предложите ваши варианты( все объекты которые я перечислил - объекты класса Turtle())

вот код:

```
from turtle import *

class Sprite(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, x, y, step, shape=shape, color=color):
        super().__init__()
        self.color(color)
        self.speed(0)
        self.shape(shape)
        self.pu()
        self.goto(x, y)
        self.pd()
        self.step = step

    def move_up(self):
        self.pu()
        self.goto(self.xcor(), self.ycor() + self.step)
        self.pd()

    def move_down(self):
        self.pu()
        self.goto(self.xcor(), self.ycor() - self.step)
        self.pd()

    def move_left(self):
        self.pu()
        self.goto(self.xcor() - self.step, self.ycor())
        self.pd()

    def move_right(self):
        self.pu()
        self.goto(self.xcor() + self.step, self.ycor())
        self.pd()

enemy1 = Sprite(100, 75, 10, 'square', 'red')
enemy2 = Sprite(-100, 0, 10, 'square', 'red')
me = Sprite(0, -30, 10, 'circle', 'black')
to = Sprite(0, 100, 0, 'triangle', 'green')
count2 = 2
count1 = 2
while 1:
    enemy1.move_left()
    enemy2.move_right()
```

Comment: Начните с демонстрации своих наработок.

Comment: исправил, добавил код